# Border around selected item on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, selection, border

In some software I'm using, a border is appearing around select items in list...

[image]

---

[image]

Any ideas on how to disable this?

Comment: That looks a little bit like an accessibility option. Do you have any high contrast or accessibility options enabled in Windows?

Comment: Yes, but the option that is there only reduced the thickness of the border. Yesterday before I shut down the pc there is no edge. I used the pc connected on tv to watch movie via hdmi. I can not understand what I might have activated to appear this.

Answer (score 1):

What solved the problem for me:

1. Navigate to Control Panel > Ease of Access > Ease of Access Center > Make the computer easier to see.
2. In the Make things easier to see section, uncheck the option "Make the focus rectangle thicker"
3. Click Apply.
   [image: Image of control panel]